# Why is my code showing that the entered number is prime even when it's not?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I used a method that checks if the entered number is prime or not. However, it is showing that the entered number is prime every time. What is the error in my logic?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ptest2 {

   static long isprime(long n){
       if ( n == 0 || n == 1 ){
           System.out.println(" Number is not prime ");
       }

       else{

       for(int i = 2; i < n; i++){
           if( n % i == 0 ) {
               System.out.println("Number is not prime ");
              }
           else  {
               System.out.println("Number is prime ");
               break;
             }
           }
       }
       return 0;
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is prime ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          long a = sc.nextLong();
        System.out.println(isprime(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: While "not prime" can be demonstrated by a **single** divisor, "prime" can be determined only after you checked **all** applicable divisors.

Comment: Off-topic:  Methods with names such as `isFoo` usually return a `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it backwards. You short-circuit your loop when you find an even divisor. As it stands, you short-circuit when you find a non-even divisor.

You have only one return which is always constant.

One would think you want your method to return `boolean` as well.

You're looking for this logic:

```
public class ptest2 {
   static boolean isprime(long n) {
       if (n == 0 || n == 1) return false;

       for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
           if (n % i == 0) {
               return false;
           }
       }

       return true;
    }
}
```

Though you also only need to iterate until the square root of `n`.

Comment: and, after testing for 2, no other even number must be tested. (BTW `0` and `1` are not considered prime)

Answer (score 0):

The function isprime() will always return 0. Is this meaningful? Well, you still have the console output.

But look at your loop:

```
for(int i = 2 ; i<n ; i++){
    if(n%i == 0 ) {
        System.out.println("Number is not prime ");
    } else  {
        System.out.println("Number is prime ");
        break;
    }
       }
}
```

Just because once a division fails the number is not a prime. All such divisions have to fail. Therefore breaking on the first occasion is wrong.

Luckily you are running the loop not until n but only as long as i is smaller than n. Otherwise you'd divide n/n which always has no remainder and thus would conclude the number is prime.